# Apparent conflict between eledmac/eledpar and the environment equation*

Tags: equations, amsmath, eledmac, eledpar

I want to make a bilingual book with parallel pages containing equations.

I use XeTeX with `eledpar`, `eledmac`, and `amsmath`.

My problem is about a strange behavior of the alignment of equations inside a eled-paragraph
`\pstart...\pend`.

Indeed, when I use the "equation" environment, the equation is correctly aligned (it is centered, with the numer-tag flushed to the right). But when I use the `equation*` environment, because I don't want the numbering, then my equation appears now flush right.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
        \pstart
I am writing something here. I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.
        \pend
        \pstart
        \begin{equation}
E=mc^2
        \end{equation}
        \pend
    \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
    I am writing something here. I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.
    \pend
    \pstart
    \begin{equation*}
E=mc^2
    \end{equation*}
    \pend
    \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Here, for exemple, the first equation is well centered but not the second one. I have the same problem if I use the environment `equation` with the option `\notag`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can consider to register (it's not mandatory) for being able to contribute again to the site. Good question!

Answer (score 1):

eledmac/eledpar is written for philological editions, where equation are not very present. It use a lot of TeX trick to split pararagraph in line to be numbered. That why some non-standards environnement (and even some standard environnement) are not fully integrated in the code.

However, as I think you don't want your equations to be in the system of line number. So you can use the trick of the optional argument of \pend or \pstart. Any content added in this optional argument will be printed after/before \pend / \pstart without being treated by the eledmac/eledpar mechanism, except for // alignement. That means, they keep the standard behavior.

So in your case, the MWE will be :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
        \pstart
I am writing something here. I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.
        \pend[
        \begin{equation}
E=mc^2
        \end{equation}
        ]
    \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
    I am writing something here. I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.I am writing something here.
    \pend[    \begin{equation*}
E=mc^2
    \end{equation*}]
    \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```